# Is there a way to enable reflink on an existing XFS filesystem?

Tags: filesystems, xfs, deduplication, reflink

I currently have a 4TB RAID 1 setup on a small, personal Linux server, which is formatted as XFS in LVM. I am interested in enabling the `reflink` feature of XFS, but I did not do so when I first created the filesystem (I used the defaults).

Is there a way that I can toggle the `reflink` feature on, without having to backup and re-create the filesystem? And if not, can I expect that feature to be implemented in the future?

Comment: By the way, the `crc` feature is enabled, which according to the documentation is necessary to enable `reflink`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading through documentation, I've found my answer:

> By default, mkfs.xfs **will create reference count btrees** and therefore will enable the reflink feature. This feature is only available for filesystems created with the (default) -m crc=1 option set. When the option -m crc=0 is used, the reference count btree feature is not **supported** and reflink is disabled.
> -- *[mkfs.xfs(8)](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/xfsprogs/mkfs.xfs.8.en.html) from Debian man pages*

The way I understand it, reference count btrees are a feature enabled on filesystem creation (the b-tree is generated differently), which *requires* CRC. CRC alone being enabled *does not imply* reference count b-trees being enabled.
There is most likely no way to get around this requirement currently.

Comment: By the way, if you're wondering about my personal server, I just dumped+converted everything to `btrfs`. idk what I expected when you can't even shrink an XFS partition without redumping

Comment: What is the fud about here? xfs will enable reflinking by default. use xfs_bmap to examine the blocks used by a file.

Comment: @user3504575 It will enable reflinking _when creating a filesystem_. This question is about enabling reflinking on an _existing_ filesystem. Back when I created that filesystem, reflinking was not enabled by default.